# Outlook 2010 Unable to See Free/Busy Information While Outlook 2007 can

Tags: exchange, windows-xp, outlook

In this office, most of us are using Outlook 2007, while a few of us uses Outlook 2010. For Outlook 2007, we are able to view other people's free busy information after hacking the registry of HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Options\Calendar and enter a new DWORD value data called 'UseLegacyFB' and set the value as 1. Once we do that, we are able to view people's free/busy information.

I don't know what to do with the Outlook 2010, since hacking the registry and updating windows did not work.

Help? :(

Comment: What version of exchange are you using?

Comment: We are using exchange 2007. Other information about this is that it displays: "No Information. 
No free/busy information could be retrieved.
Your server location could not be determined. Contact your administrator."

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the Exchange 'Availability Service' is not functioning correctly on your Client Access Server.

In Exchange 2007, Free/Busy information is available via two technologies. The old/legacy system is storing it in Public Folders, whereas the new tech is via a Web Service called the Availability Service.

Outlook 2007 can be set to use the old Free/Busy tech using the UseLegacyFB registry key, but Outlook 2010 has no support for this.

Please have a look at [this Microsoft TechNet article on "Troubleshooting Free/Busy Information for Outlook 2007"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397225%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)